# Stripes in background color drawn by listings package

Tags: latex, listings

I'm trying to create a verbatim environment with a colored background and which can span across pages (so using a colorbox is not an option). It seemed that the listings package was a good way towards it, but the background is drawn one line at a time, such that, when I view the PDF, I see annoying white-ish "stripes" between the lines as well as where the invisible (0pt) frame rule was not to be drawn:

http://a.imageshack.us/img202/9928/lststrips.png

Here's the minimal code I used to create the output shown in the image:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{gray},
  frame=single, framerule=0pt, framesep=5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
 if (a < b)
 {
    printf("A is smaller than  B!\n");
 }
 a = b;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Is there any workaround against these 'stripes'?

Comment: Off topic. Belongs on tex.SE

Comment: Since when is LaTeX off-topic here...

Comment: It is at tex.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403147/.

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround would be to not specify a color for the listings themselves, put instead use a `\colorbox`, but for that to work, you either need to use `\lstinputlisting` or store the result in a box using e.g. `lrbox`.

```
\newbox{\mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
 if (a < b)
 {
    printf("A is smaller than  B!\n");
 }
 a = b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\colorbox{gray}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

**UPDATE:** However, a more beautiful solution is to use [Donald Arseneau's framed.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/framed/), which also allows the source-code to span multiple pages.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{gray} 
\begin{shaded}
\begin{lstlisting}
 if (a < b)
 {
    printf("A is smaller than  B!\n");
 }
 a = b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that, by wrapping it inside a \colorbox, the lstlisting environment loses the possibility of spanning across pages.

Comment: Hi grddev. I like your solution using the `framed` package. One problem is that the line numbers and lstlistings caption are occluded, in whole or in part, by the shaded box. Do you know a work-around? Thanks.